# Swift Dictionary(grouping: by) order by date

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have an array of tuples "recentPayments", that contains a date and a subscriptionItem(custom class I made). I would like to order this into groups by month. I used Dictionary(grouping: by) to do this and it works and outputs into "transactionsByMonth" variable, that contains a string for the month and year and this corresponds to a recent payment item. The only problem is this outputs in an irregular order, the months aren't in order. I have tried many things but could not fix it, and can find no similar things online. Thanks for any help.

```
var recentPayments: [(Date, SubscriptionItem)] = []
@State var transactionsByMonth: [String: [(Date, SubscriptionItem)]] = [:]

func getPaymentsByMonths() {
    transactionsByMonth = Dictionary(grouping: recentPayments) { $0.0.formatted(.dateTime.year().month()) }
}
```

Comment: `Dictionary`, is by definition, not ordered. If you want an ordered dictionary, check out `OrderedDictionary` in swift-collections

Comment: Thanks for the response, I swapped dictionary to be ordered dictionary and I get this error. Cannot assign value of type 'OrderedDictionary<Date.FormatStyle.FormatOutput, [(Date, SubscriptionItem)]>' (aka 'OrderedDictionary<String, Array<(Date, SubscriptionItem)>>') to type '[String : [(Date, SubscriptionItem)]]'

Comment: Yep -- those aren't the same type. You'd need to change the definition to match -- ie change the second one to match the first one. You'll also have to write code to order the months

Comment: Thanks again, you're amazing. I already had it sorting into groups by month, it just was ordered wrong, for example (Mar, Jan, Aug, May). I changed the declaration of "transactionsByMonth" to `@State var transactionsByMonth: OrderedDictionary<String, [(Date, SubscriptionItem)]> = [:]` that declares it as an ordered dictionary and now it works perfectly. Really thanks so much. 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Dictionary`, is by definition, not ordered. If you want an ordered dictionary, check out `OrderedDictionary` in [swift-collections](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections)